# PR2 controller on custom robot, no joints listed

Tags: ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to run a controller on a joint in gazebo. I can control joints of the Pr2 and the pendulum example. But if I want to control my own urdf then joints are not visible.

```
rosrun pr2_controller_manager pr2_controller_manager list-joints
Waiting for mechanism statistics message...
```

Only transmissions and controller manager block should be present in the urdf?
My urdf:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>

<robot name="ar_arm">

 <link name="world" />

 <link name="arm_base">
 <inertial>
    <origin xyz="0.000000 0.000000 0.000990" rpy="0.000000 -0.000000 0.000000"/>
    <mass value="101.000000" />
    <inertia ixx="1.110000" ixy="0.000000" ixz="0.000000" iyy="100.110000" iyz="0.000000" izz="1.010000"/>
  </inertial>
  <collision name="arm_base_geom">
    <origin  xyz="0.000000 0.000000 0.050000" rpy="0.000000 -0.000000 0.000000"/>
    <geometry>
      <box size="1.000000 1.000000 0.100000"/>
    </geometry>
  </collision>
  <visual>
    <origin xyz="0.000000 0.000000 0.050000" rpy="0.000000 -0.000000 0.000000"/>
    <geometry>
      <box size="1.000000 1.000000 0.100000"/>
    </geometry>
    <material name="Cyan">
     <color rgba="0 1 1  1.0"/>
    </material>     
  </visual> 
</link>

<link name="arm_cylinder">
 <inertial>
     <origin xyz="0.000000 0.000000 0.600000" rpy="0.000000 -0.000000 0.000000"/>
  <mass value="1.000000" />
  <inertia ixx="0.110000" ixy="0.000000" ixz="0.000000" iyy="100.110000" iyz="0.000000" izz="1.010000"/>
  </inertial>
  <collision name="arm_base_geom_arm_trunk">
    <origin  xyz="0.000000 0.000000 0.600000" rpy="0.000000 -0.000000 0.000000"/>
    <geometry>
      <cylinder radius="0.050000" length="1.00000"/>
    </geometry>
  </collision>
  <visual name="arm_base_geom_arm_trunk_visual" cast_shadows="1">
    <origin xyz="0.000000 0.000000 0.650000" rpy="0.000000 -0.000000 0.000000"/>
    <geometry>
      <cylinder radius="0.050000" length="1.100000"/>
    </geometry>
    <material name="Red">
    <color rgba="255 0 0 1"/>
    </material>
  </visual>
</link>

<link name="arm_shoulder_pan">
  <inertial>  
    <mass value="1.100000"/>
    <origin xyz="0.045455 0.000000 0.000000" rpy="0.000000 -0.000000 0.000000"/>
    <inertia ixx="0.011000" ixy="0.000000" ixz="0.000000" iyy="0.022500" iyz="0.000000" izz="0.013500"/>
  </inertial>
 
  <collision name="arm_shoulder_pan_geom_arm_shoulder">
    <origin xyz="0.550000 0.000000 0.050000" rpy="0.000000 -0.000000 0.000000"/>
    <geometry>
      <box size="1.000000 0.050000 0.100000"/>
    </geometry>
  </collision>
  <visual name="arm_shoulder_pan_geom_arm_shoulder_visual" cast_shadows="1">
    <origin xyz="0.550000 0.000000 0.050000" rpy="0.000000 -0.000000 0.000000"/>
    <geometry>
      <box size="1.000000 0.050000 0.100000"/>
    </geometry>
    <material name="Cyan">
     <color rgba="0 1 1  1.0"/>
    </material>
  </visual>
</link>

<link name="arm_shoulder_pivot">
   <inertial>  
    <mass value="0.100001"/>
    <origin xyz="0.045455 0.000000 0.000000" rpy="0.000000 -0.000000 0.000000"/>
    <inertia ixx="0.011000" ixy="0.000000" ixz="0.000000" iyy="0.022500" iyz="0.000000" izz="0.013500"/>
  </inertial>
<collision name="arm_shoulder_pan_geom">
    <origin pose="0.000000 0.000000 0.050000 0.000000 -0.000000 0.000000"/>
    <geometry>
      <cylinder radius="0.050000" length="0.100000"/>
    </geometry>
  </collision>
  <visual name="arm_shoulder_pan_geom_visual" cast_shadows="1">
    <origin pose="0.050000 0.000000 0.050000" rpy="0.000000 0.000000 0.000000"/>
    <geometry>
      <cylinder radius="0.050000" length="0.200000"/>
    </geometry>
    <material name="Red">
    <color rgba="255 0 0 1"/>
    </material>
  </visual>
</link>

<link name="arm_elbow_pan">
<inertial>
<mass value="1.200000"/>
    <origin xyz="0.087500 0.000000 0.083333" rpy="0.000000 -0.000000 0.000000"/>
    <inertia ixx="0.031000" ixy="0.000000" ixz="-0.005000" iyy="0.072750" iyz="0.000000" izz="0.044750"/>
 </inertial>
<collision name="arm_elbow_pan_geom_arm_elbow">
    <origin  xyz="0.300000 0.000000 0.150000" rpy="0.000000 -0.000000 0.000000"/>
    <geometry>
      <box size="0.500000 0.030000 0.100000"/>
    </geometry>
  </collision>
  <visual name="arm_elbow_pan_geom_arm_elbow_visual" cast_shadows="1">
    <origin  xyz="0.2500000 0.000000 0.000000" rpy="0.000000 0.000000 0.000000"/>
    <geometry>
      <box size="0.500000 0.030000 0.100000"/>
    </geometry>
    <material name="Cyan">
     <color rgba="0 1 1  1.0"/>
     </material>
  </visual>
</link>

<joint name="arm_base_joint" type="fixed">    
  <parent link="world"/>
  <child link="arm_base"/>
  <axis xyz="0.000000 0.000000 1.00000">
    <limit lower="0.000000" upper="0.000000"/>
     <dynamics damping="10.0" friction="10.0"/>
  </axis>
</joint>
 
<joint name="arm_base_cylinder" type="fixed">   
 <parent link="arm_base"/>
  <child link="arm_cylinder"/>
  <axis xyz="0.000000 0.000000 1.000000">
    <limit lower="0.000000" upper="0.000000"/>
     <dynamics damping="10.0" friction="10.0"/>
  </axis>
</joint>
   
<joint name="arm_shoulder_pan_joint" type="continuous">
  <parent link="arm_cylinder"/>
  <child link="arm_shoulder_pan"/>
  <origin xyz="0.000000 0.000000 1.100000"/>
  <axis xyz="0.000000 0.000000 1.000000">
     <dynamics damping="10.0" friction="10.0"/>
  </axis>
</joint>

<joint name="arm_elbow_fix" type="fixed">
  <parent link="arm_shoulder_pan"/>
  <child link="arm_shoulder_pivot"/>
  <origin xyz="1.100000 0.000000 0.100000"/>
  <axis xyz="0.000000 0.000000 1.000000">
     <dynamics damping="10.0" friction="10.0"/>
  </axis>
</joint>

<joint name="arm_elbow_pan_joint" type="continuous">
  <parent link="arm_shoulder_pivot"/>
  <child link="arm_elbow_pan"/>
  <origin xyz="0.00000 0.000000 0.0500000"/>
  <axis xyz="0.000000 0.000000 1.000000">
     <dynamics damping="10.0" friction="10.0"/>
  </axis>
</joint>


<!-- PR2_ACTARRAY -->
    <controller:gazebo_ros_controller_manager name="gazebo_ros_controller_manager" plugin="libgazebo_ros_controller_manager.so">
      <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
      <updateRate>1000.0</updateRate>
    </controller:gazebo_ros_controller_manager>
    <!-- gazebo_ros_p3d for position groundtruth -->
    <controller:gazebo_ros_p3d name="p3d_link1_controller" plugin="libgazebo_ros_p3d.so">
      <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
      <updateRate>1000.0</updateRate>
      <bodyName>link1</bodyName>
      <topicName>link1_pose</topicName>
      <frameName>map</frameName>
      <interface:position name="p3d_link1_position"/>
    </controller:gazebo_ros_p3d>
  </gazebo>
  <!-- mechanism controls -->
  <transmission name="link1_trans" type="pr2_mechanism_model/SimpleTransmission">
    <actuator name="link1_motor"/>
    <joint name="arm_shoulder_pan_joint"/>
    <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
    <motorTorqueConstant>1</motorTorqueConstant>
  </transmission>

</robot>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60699/pr2-controller-on-custom-robot,-no-joints-listed../) by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2573 on 2013-04-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The solution is that you have to but the urdf in the robot description! Although not documented this is required (probably for the p3d).

```
  <param name="robot_description" command="cat '$(find package)/model/model.urdf'" />
```

---

Originally posted by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) with karma: 2573 on 2013-04-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0